# How to style parts in a similar way as chapters with the memoir class

Tags: memoir

I use the `memoir` class to write a long document which includes `parts`. I use the following code to style my chapters, and I would like to style the parts in a very similar way.

```
\makeatletter 
\newlength\dlf@normtxtw 
\setlength\dlf@normtxtw{\textwidth} 
\def\myhelvetfont{\def\sfdefault{mdput}} 
\newsavebox{\feline@chapter} 
\newcommand\feline@chapter@marker[1][4cm]{%
    \sbox\feline@chapter{% 
        \resizebox{!}{#1}{\fboxsep=1pt%
            \colorbox{darkBlue}{\color{white}\bfseries\sffamily\thechapter}% 
        }}%
    \rotatebox{90}{% 
        \resizebox{%
            \heightof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}+\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}% 
            {!}{\scshape\so\@chapapp}}\quad%
            \raisebox{\depthof{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}}{\usebox{\feline@chapter}}%
} 
\newcommand\feline@chm[1][4cm]{%
\sbox\feline@chapter{\feline@chapter@marker[#1]}% 
\makebox[0pt][l]{% aka \rlap
\makebox[1cm][r]{\usebox\feline@chapter}%
}} 
\makechapterstyle{daleif1}{
\renewcommand\chapnamefont{\normalfont\Large\sffamily\scshape\raggedleft\so} 
\renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\normalfont\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{darkBlue}}        %\scshape ?
\renewcommand\chapternamenum{} 
\renewcommand\printchaptername{} 
\renewcommand\printchapternum{\null\hfill\feline@chm[2.5cm]\par} 
\renewcommand\afterchapternum{\par\vskip\midchapskip} 
\renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{\chaptitlefont\raggedleft ##1\par}
} 
\makeatother 
\chapterstyle{daleif1}
```

I can't find a part equivalent to `makechapterstyle`.

Comment: Please provide complete compilable code. It is hard to test only a snippet.

Comment: Apologies for not providing something that compiles. See my comment to your answer, very useful already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't compile your snippet (the chapter number styling) but the following lines in the preamble reproduce the rest of the chapter styling.

```
\renewcommand\partnamefont{\normalfont\Large\sffamily\scshape\raggedleft\so} 
\renewcommand\parttitlefont{\normalfont\huge\sffamily\bfseries\color{blue}}        %
\renewcommand\partnamenum{} 
\renewcommand\printpartname{} 
\renewcommand\printpartnum{\parttitlefont\raggedleft\thepart} % added for parts <<<<<
\renewcommand\printparttitle[1]{\chaptitlefont\raggedleft #1}
```

[image: b]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this already clarifies things quite a bit and I managed to integrate that with the rest of my code.